# Repeatable pattern matching

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Consider the following simple example.

```
type PaymentInstrument =
    | Check of string
    | CreditCard of string * DateTime

let printInstrumentName instrument = 
    match instrument with 
    | Check number-> printfn "check"
    | CreditCard (number, expirationDate) -> printfn "card"

let printRequisites instrument =
    match instrument with 
    | Check number -> printfn "check %s" number
    | CreditCard (number, expirationDate) -> printfn "card %s %A" number expirationDate
```

As you can see the same pattern matching logic is repeated in two functions. If I would use OOP I would create interface `IPaymentInstrument`, define two operations:

`PrintInstrumentName` and `PrintRequisites`

and then implement classes - one per payment instrument. To instantiate instrument depending on some external conditions I would use (for example) the factory pattern (`PaymentInstrumentFactory`).

If I would need to add a new payment instrument, I just need to add a new class which implements `IPaymentInstrument` interface and update factory instantiating logic. Other code that uses these classes remains as is.

But if I use the functional approach I should update *each* function where pattern matching on this type exists.

If there will be a lot of functions using `PaymentInstrument` type that will be a problem.

How to eliminate this problem using functional approach?

Comment: You could make these member functions which would be slightly neater, but still have the repeated matching

Comment: It's one side of [expression problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExpressionProblem), while OOP approach is the other. Ergo, you really can't eliminate the pattern match.

Comment: I concur with @PatrykĆwiek's comment. The power of pattern match is that you eliminate the "noise" of OOP mechanisms, barely useful in this case. In real-life projects, the inner bodies of each branch sit in separate functions which simplifies development and testing. OTOH, if on some day `PaymentInstrument` grows big and it becomes developed by different people, then you may quickly switch to OOP approach, while retaining existing separate processing functions.

Comment: In case you are talking about the expression problem (which you would not really solve with your interface as you had to update it with more functions for the second part) then either just go OOP or you can try the *simulated typeclass* approach (which kindof works with F#s static-constraint caps) - this would be the FP side of the solution

Comment: btw: I would **not** sacrifice the goodness you get with ADT by going OOP ... this is obviously a domain-problem so there should be *zero* reason to add things outside the domain-assembly (meaning: of course you would add the cases in **your** code and provide additional functions just as you did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mark Seemann's answer I came to such design decision.

```
type PaymentInstrument =
    | Check of string
    | CreditCard of string * DateTime

type Operations =
    { 
      PrintInstrumentName : unit -> unit
      PrintRequisites : unit -> unit
    }

let getTypeOperations instrument =
    match instrument with 
    | Check number-> 
        let printCheckNumber () = printfn "check"
        let printCheckRequisites () = printfn "check %s" number
        { PrintInstrumentName = printCheckNumber; PrintRequisites = printCheckRequisites }
    | CreditCard (number, expirationDate) -> 
        let printCardNumber () = printfn "card"
        let printCardRequisites () = printfn "card %s %A" number expirationDate
        { PrintInstrumentName = printCardNumber; PrintRequisites = printCardRequisites }
```

And usage

```
let card = CreditCard("124", DateTime.Now)
let operations = getTypeOperations card
operations.PrintInstrumentName()
operations.PrintRequisites()
```

As you can see the `getTypeOperations` function  executes the role of factory pattern. To aggregate functions in a one bunch I use simple record type (however, according to F# design guidelines http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/ interfaces are preferred to such decision but I am interested to do it in functional approach for now to understand it better).

I got what I wanted - pattern matching is in only one place for now.

Answer (score 17):

As Patryk Ćwiek points out in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298466/repeatable-pattern-matching#comment54396004_33298466), you're encountering the [Expression Problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExpressionProblem), so you'll have to choose one or the other.

If the ability to add more data types is more important to you than the ability to easily add more behaviour, then an interface-based approach may be more appropriate.

In F#, you can still define object-oriented interfaces:

```
type IPaymentInstrument =
    abstract member PrintInstrumentName : unit -> unit
    abstract member PrintRequisites : unit -> unit
```

You can also create classes that implement this interface. Here's `Check`, and I'll leave `CreditCard` as an exercise to the reader:

```
type Check(number : string) =
    interface IPaymentInstrument with
        member this.PrintInstrumentName () = printfn "check"
        member this.PrintRequisites () = printfn "check %s" number
```

Yet, if you want to go the object-oriented way, you should begin to consider the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), one of which is the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP). Once you start applying the ISP aggressively, [you'll ultimately end up with interfaces with a single member, like this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional):

```
type IPaymentInstrumentNamePrinter =
    abstract member PrintInstrumentName : unit -> unit

type IPaymentInstrumentRequisitePrinter =
    abstract member PrintRequisites : unit -> unit
```

You can still implement this in classes:

```
type Check2(number : string) =
    interface IPaymentInstrumentNamePrinter with
        member this.PrintInstrumentName () = printfn "check"
    interface IPaymentInstrumentRequisitePrinter with
        member this.PrintRequisites () = printfn "check %s" number
```

This is beginning to seem slightly ridiculous now. If you're using F#, then **why go to all the trouble of defining an interface with a single member?**

Why not, instead, use **functions**?

Both desired interface members have the type `unit -> unit` (not a particularly 'functionally' looking type, though), so why not pass such functions around, and dispense with the interface overhead?

With the `printInstrumentName` and `printRequisites` functions from the OP, you already have the desired behaviour. If you want to turn them into polymorphic 'objects' that 'implement' the desired interface, you can close over them:

```
let myCheck = Check "1234"
let myNamePrinter () = printInstrumentName myCheck
```

In Functional Programming, we don't call these things *objects*, but rather *closures*. Instead of being *data with behaviour*, they're *behaviour with data*.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Using it I came up to this decision http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319572/446115